# Signature pad Storing the signature in Database

Tags: database, storage, signature, pad

I have develop a signature using Html and java script where user can perform a signature,.

help will be appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what sort of DB you want to use to store the signature.

If you're using Rails and Amazon's S3 service you can use Active_Storage to assign the signature to a user.

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html
https://keithpblog.org/post/active-storage-on-amazon-s3/

I'm using https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad on the front end for capturing the user's input.